# truffle test: SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Tags: truffle-test

```
 truffle test
Using network 'development'.


Compiling your contracts...
===========================
> Everything is up to date, there is nothing to compile.

/home/ubuntutest/proyectoico/test/testMasterICO.js:18
  it("Does the first buy"; async function() {
     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:743:23)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:810:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:666:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:606:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:598:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:705:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:14:16)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:231:27
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Mocha.loadFiles (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:228:14)
    at Mocha.run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:536:10)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/truffle-core/lib/test.js:118:1
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/next_tick.js:81:5)

 Truffle v5.0.7 (core: 5.0.7)
Node v11.11.0
```

The code in the contract:

```
  it("Does the first buy"; async function() {
    const preBalance = await masterToken.balanceOf(addressTokenHolder1);
    const preTotalEth = await web3.eth.getBalance(addressEther);
    await masterToken.sendTransaction({
      value: web3.toWei(1),
      gas: 300000,
      gasPrice: "20000000000",
      from: addressTokenHolder1
    });
    const postBalance = await masterToken.balanceOf(addressTokenHolder1);
    const postTotalEth = await web3.eth.getBalance(addressEther);
    const currentBalance = postBalance - preBalance;
    const currentTotalEth = postTotalEth - preTotalEth;
    assert.equal(web3.fromWei(currentBalance), 1);
    assert.equal(web3.fromWei(currentTotalEth), 1);
  });
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: This has nothing to do with Ethereum. Your JavaScript simply has invalid syntax. Hard to be sure without seeing the rest of the code, but I assume the semicolon should be a comma.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely, this line is wrong:

`it("Does the first buy"; async function() {`

The function `it` takes two arguments, a description of the test you're running and an async function that executes that test. They must be separated by a comma.